# Non-distro specific, linux tweaking, hacking and learning support IRC

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, irc

Distro-specific support channels are good only if you run their clean stable versions out of the box and basically don't install anything other than what you get out of the box. But what about those who want to play around and experiment and learn a little bit more?

I'm looking for a non-distro-specific channel that will offer support and troubleshooting advice for people who have hacked their machine to shreds.

I am really having a hard time finding support and a positive atmosphere when it comes to experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are such channels (often called #linux) in many networks. The problem is, that if people use them as a general helpline for everything, there will be way too much traffic. So they'll often use FAQ, RTFM and "you broke it, you fix it" as the policy.

Also, Linux is the kernel, nothing more. If you're using a distribution, almost everything depends on the integration done in that distribution. If you're using a particular piece of software, everything depends on that. And if you've changed anything while experimenting, you get to deal with maintaining your changes.

There's no way that an irc channel could support the diversity in all that. Although, if you find some knowledgeable contacts, you may get a surprisingly wide array of "support", but you'll be bothering them. And so will everyone else.

Of course, you could set up a channel if you think the world needs one :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the LFS channel on irc.linuxfromscratch.org.

I haven't been there in a long time, but they were great when I had questions.